# Extract data with preg_match

Tags: preg-match, capture

I have this string:

```
8d25a8dfdf46": { "file": "images\/slide\/s1.jpg", "title": "", "link"
```

I want to capture:

from here:

```
"file": "capture inside this quotes"
```

To that ultimate quote

Thanks in advance!

NOTE: my string have more data, i just put a section of it.

Comment: You string looks like JSON, use `json_decode` to read the information.

Comment: Use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/function.json-decode.php) to decode your string to an array. It's much better and safer as regex

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
preg_match('/"file": "([^"]*)"/', $string, $match);
```

`$match[0]` will contain the entire match, `$match[1]` will contain the image URL.

Comment: Almost there, the code give me this->

"file": "images\/slide\/s1.jpg"

i need to capture olny images\/slide\/s1.jpg but validating the predecesor "file":

Comment: Why didn't you say that in the question? And can't you figure out  by yourself how to use a capture group to get the part you want?

Comment: Sorry, i am new in stackoverflow and in this promramer level :(

Comment: I found the solution i jus modified what you give me to this:

'/"file": "([^"]*)"/'

$match[1]

Thank you very much!! :D

Comment: That's the same modification I made 20 minutes ago.